# User and group database

Tags: database, database-design

i need to create a database that has User information and Group information but i come to a deadlock when i try to design my database.

I decided my tables "User", "Group" and "Connections"

"Connections" table shows which user is member of a group.

"User" table has columns "Email(PK), Name, Surname, Password"
  "Group" table has columns "GKey(GroupKey PK),GName,Amail(Admin e-mail)
   "Connections" table has columns "Email(FK),GKey(FK)

When new user clicks "sign up button" "User" table will be filled.
When user clicks "create group", "Group" and "Connections" will be filled but how "Connections" table will be filled. In this point, i come to a deadlock.

I think i decided my tables and their columns wrong or missing, also "add people to group" button in my Java program is another issue for this database.(The admin that has logged in in my Java program will be able to add his group people that signed up. Admin will use e-mail addresses for adding people to group.)(I know it is not a good idea but i will start with this)

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: correcting my ideas. i saw something like that is done in this website, he asked about his database and people corrected him.

Comment: If this is a general `database` schema design question, your other tags are irrelevant.

Comment: okay i am sorry i will delete them

Comment: It is traditional for questions to have a question.

Comment: you are right, people should try to help instead of asking questions to owner of the question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks fine :/ ...apart from one little thing

Users needs a pk and details about users

Groups needs a pk and details about the groups

That much you have.

Connections should then have a pk and a fk for each of the other tables which I dont think you have(use an id column for a pk).

If you do that it will give you a many to many relationship between groups and users.